c++ code to read remote txt file from URL and store it as is to const char* [] array
I'm trying to create a cpp program that will read remote file from URL, for example, http://10.10.10.10/file.txt
File contains words in this format "word1","word2","word3"
I have to store file content to array "const char* wordslist[3]={"word1","word2","word3"}" as is.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <wininet.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "wininet.lib")

// Function to parse the input string and populate the wordlist array
void parseAndPopulate(const std::string& input, const char** wordlist, int size) {
    std::vector<std::string> words;
    size_t pos = 0;
    while ((pos = input.find("\",\"", pos)) != std::string::npos) {
        words.push_back(input.substr(1, pos - 1)); // Extract word between quotes
        pos += 3; // Move past the ", delimiter
    }
    // Add the last word (no ", delimiter at the end)
    words.push_back(input.substr(pos + 2, input.size() - pos - 3));
    // Check if the size matches
    if (words.size() != size) {
        std::cerr << "Error: Number of words in the file does not match the specified size\n";
        return;
    }

    // Copy words to wordlist array
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        wordlist[i] = words[i].c_str();
    }
}

int main() {
    const int size = 3; // Size of wordlist array
    const char* wordlist[size]; //This does not work!!!!!!

    // URL to fetch data from
    const char* url = "10.10.10.10/file.txt";

    HINTERNET hInternet = InternetOpenA("HTTPGET", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
    if (hInternet != NULL) {
        HINTERNET hUrlFile = InternetOpenUrlA(hInternet, url, NULL, 0, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 0);
        if (hUrlFile != NULL) {
            std::string readBuffer;
            char buffer[1024];
            DWORD bytesRead = 0;

            while (InternetReadFile(hUrlFile, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &bytesRead) && bytesRead > 0) {
                readBuffer.append(buffer, bytesRead);
            }

            // Close the URL file handle
            InternetCloseHandle(hUrlFile);

            // Parse the fetched data and populate the wordlist array
            parseAndPopulate(readBuffer, wordlist, size);

            // Print the populated wordlist array
            for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
                std::cout << wordlist[i] << std::endl;
            }
        }
        else {
            std::cerr << "Error: Failed to open URL " << url << std::endl;
        }

        // Close the internet handle
        InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "Error: Failed to initialize WinINet" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}


How to accomplish this?
I need "const char* wordlist[];" look like this:
const char* wordlist[3]={"word1","word2","word3"};

//This does not work!!!!!! Why? What happens if you do it?

First, comment-out all code referencing the URL.  Second, create a hard-coded array of data.  Thirdly, extract your code out of main and into a function.  Change main() to read from the array and pass the data to your function.  Get this working, and backup before proceeding to the URL stuff.

You probably should use a std::vector<std::string> instead of wordlist or maybe std::set<std::string> I am unsure what the purpose of this wordlist is.

In your current code your bug is: wordlist[i] = words[i].c_str(); Remember that c_str() returns a pointer to memory that will no longer be valid when the string  is reallocated or freed. So when words goes out of scope in parseAndPopulate() all the pointers in wordlist are invalid / dangling pointers.

Another idea is to remove the URL stuff and create a data file in your local folder.  Test your program by reading from the local file.  When that works, back it up and add the URL stuff and continue.

Please don't parse CSV files like that. It's messy and broken.

You have to change const char* wordlist[size]; to char* wordlist[size];, because you change the char* later. You have also to change the paramter const char** wordlist to char* wordlist[].
In the for-loop in parseAndPopulate(...) you have to change your code to
wordlist[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(words[i].c_str()));
strcpy(wordlist[i], words[i].c_str());

malloc allocates the memory needed for the c_str and returns the pointer to that memory.
strcpy copies the c_str from the words[i] to the allocated memory.
